# Probability of the number of heads given a number of coin flips

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, combinations, binomial-distribution

I've been learning statistics through the website Khan Academy and they have this [problem](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/binomial-random-variables/v/binomial-distribution):

> Let the random variable X = the # of heads from flipping a coin 5
>   times. The total number of outcomes from 5 flips = 32. Figure out the probability that the random variable takes on
>   0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. The instructor then answers the problem by giving  the probabilities below:
>
> P(X = 0) = 1/32
>
> P(X = 1) = 5/32
>
> P(X = 2) = 10/32
>
> P(X = 3) = 10/32
>
> P(X = 4) = 5/32
>
> P(X = 5) = 1/32

The way he got the probabilities/answers is through using combinations: $$\frac{_{5}C_X}{32} $$

I've spent so much time trying to find out why the instructor uses combinations here. Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the combinations function $_nC_k$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects. To find the number of ways to flip $x$ heads when you flip $5$ coins, you must sum the probabilities of each different way of doing this. There are $_5C_x$ ways to “choose” which $x$ coins come up heads. For example, for $x=2$:
$$HHTTT$$
$$HTHTT$$
$$HTTHT$$
$$HTTTH$$
$$THHTT$$
$$THTHT$$
$$THTTH$$
$$TTHHT$$
$$TTHTH$$
$$TTTHH$$
There are $_5 C_2=10$ ways to do this, and the probability of each option is $1/2^5$, so the total probability of getting $2$ heads is $_5 C_2/2^5$. More generally, the probability of flipping $x$ heads is
$$\frac{_5 C_x}{2^5}$$

Comment: I thought that when we use combinations, we don't care about order? Aren't all the outcomes that you just listed the same outcomes but just in a different order?

Comment: When you use combinations, you don’t care about the order in which the things are chosen. Think of it this way: if we want to flip 5 coins so that 2 come up heads, we much choose two of the flips to come up heads. But if we choose the 2nd and 3rd flips (say), this is the same as choosing the 3rd and 2nd flips.

Comment: But if we choose the 2nd and 3rd flips, isn't that the same as choosing the 4th and 5th flips as it still has an outcome of 2 heads out of 5 flips?

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated way to look at this is to realize that X is a binomial random variable, with probability of success (head) equal to $p =0.5$ and number of trials (toin cosses) $n=5$. If, for example, you compute $P(X=1)$ for this binomial distribution using one of the calculators available online, you will obtain 0.3125, that is, $5/32$.